# Checking if username is in datatable in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, datatable

I'm working on VS2010 c#.

I have a datatable containing username and passwords:

```
____________
andy | 1234
joni | 5678
lara | 4567
```

How do I form a function that will see what the user entered in a textbox and review if it is in the database or not?

Comment: This will depend on the details that you haven't provided. What does the DataTable look like, for instance?

Comment: isn't the 3 columns I've given enough? the names of the columns are userName and password.

Comment: Any primary key? Uniqueness constraints? Etc? Also, you have me assuming that all of your data is already in the `DataTable`, but that's only because you didn't include any code for filling the table, so I have to guess.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a `SQL Function` and do something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckUserExists] (@User NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @RetVal INT

SELECT @RetVal = COUNT(User.UserId)
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    Users.Username = @User

IF @RetVal > 0 
BEGIN
   RETURN 1
END
    RETURN 0
END
```

Then in your C# program you could use `ADO.NET` and do:

```
private bool UserExists(string username) {
     SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("CheckUserExists", conn);

 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@User", username));

     SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // execute the function

     // return the response from the reader (1 if it is true, 0 for false)
}
```

You could then call the function by doing:

```
 var userExists = UserExists("YourUser");
```

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx

Comment: Note this may or may not be case sensitive depending on the database, settings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a select statement on a datatable which will return an array of DataRows's.

```
DataRow[] foundRows = DataTable.Select("username = andy");
if(foundRows.Length > 0)
{
Console.WriteLine("Username exists");
}
```